# Google Recaptcha Issue Issue

Tags: reactjs

I am using ([react-google-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha)) in my project. Following error return by google Recaptcha when I deployed my app on Heroku. It is working fine on my local setup.

ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTkgi.png)

Comment: Have you set the Domains field properly in your 
reCAPTCHA settings? see: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/settings
The setting should be aligned with your Heroku host.

Comment: Yes is it of limited use like free up to a specific number of clicks?